# How to enable PayPal Website Payments Standard & Express Checkout at the same time?

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal

We were asked to enable PayPal Express Checkout for a client (in addition to Website Payments Standard).

I understand that the default behaviour in Magento is to have only one PayPal-based solution enabled at a time, and when you enable one of the other PayPal solutions it informs you that the other will be turned off:

[image]

The client wants to continue to be able to offer PayPal Website Payments Standard as a payment option at checkout for those customers who don't want to use Express Checkout or who miss the Express Checkout button on the cart page.

How can we enable both Website Payments Standard ***and*** Express Checkout at the same time?

This other thread asks the same question but the only comment that was added does not answer the question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901121/enable-both-paypal-standard-and-paypal-express-checkout-payment-methods-in-magen

The store is running on Magento CE 1.7.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "PayPal Express Checkout" and have it also as a payment option in the cart (even if user missed previous areas)?  I know that I ran into similar situation  I am running 1.9.2  so this may be different.

In Advanced settings you can use the option "Display on Shopping Cart"
[image]

In 1.9.x it adds to the checkout page.
Again, this is a test environment, but it does add it to checkout as you can see the Paypal image.

[image]

Comment: Image is from a test environment.

Comment: Are you sure this shows PayPal as a payment method when checking out? I am referring to the fourth step of the checkout process where the customer selects from the available payment methods (not on the cart page). We want them to be able to select PayPal as a payment method as is offered when Website Payments Standard is enabled (in addition to being able to use the Express Checkout button on the cart page).

Comment: Yes, do you want screenshot?

Comment: Yes please, if you don't mind ;) I think the "Display on Shopping Cart" option is for adding the Express Checkout button to the cart page, not adding it as a payment method to the checkout process. I may be wrong...

Comment: I think you're right about this option.  But even if that is the optional part and by default it adds it to the checkout it should solve your issues as you want both.  It will also add it in the mini cart in header.  For that you will disable by css if you want removed.  Answer updating with image for checkout.

Comment: I tried with `base/default` theme instead of our custom theme and PayPal is shown as a payment method, so it's the custom theme that is hiding PayPal at checkout. The answer above is therefore correct to enable the _"Display on shopping cart"_ setting.